# Excel combine rows from multiple spreadsheets into one

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate an excel document. Everyday i have to make some report about aquisition from the other day. I have a excel document, with 5 spreadsheets... where i write dates depending on the type.

| Date | Suplier | Object | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/04 | aaaa | xxxxx | xxx |
| 12/04 | aa | xxxx | x |

So, every spread sheet it's design like this (see above), and i want a code or something, when specific date is fulfilled ( in all 5 spreedsheet) to copy automatic that row into another spreadsheet ( summary), one after another. And if it's possible to be sorted by supplier.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please either show us your attempt(s). This isn't a request-forum for code, we're here to help others with code/issues :)  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if u have the formula `VSTACK` and `SORT`, they should do the trick. no VBA needed